# Why Guava eventbus (the module) is not extensible?

Tags: java, guava, event-bus

In the latest version (and in the previous versions too), Guava eventbus module is not extensible. Currently, it uses Subscriber and `SubscriberRegistry` internally to decide on dispatching the event. But these classes are made package-private and hence not extensible. If `Subscriber` and `SubscriberRegistry` were made as a public interface, it would let others to provide their own implementation in deciding the `Subscriber`.

Let me explain my usecase to make more sense here. Lets say I have a hierarchy of classes which have a common set of events (create/updated/delete). And there are listeners who listen to one or more of these events for one or more of these classes. To be able to use `EventBus` model, now, I have to have three event classes created for each type of the classes.

If I have `class A` and `class B extends A` and `class C extends B` and `class D extends A`, and each of A, B, C, and D could be created/updated/deleted. Then I have to have `ACreatedEvent`, `AUpdatedEvent`, `ADeletedEvent`, `BCreatedEvent`, `BUpdatedEvent`, `BDeletedEvent`, and so on for all the classes. (I know that subscribing for `ACreatedEvent` will be notified if `BCreatedEvent` is posted, assuming `BCreatedEvent extends ACreatedEvent` and so on. But there could be listeners who are specifically interested in a sub class object event and not super class object event. So, this bloated hierarchy of events is necessary to give the flexibility for the listeners).

This forces me to created so many Event classes which is very clumsy. What I thought was, to introduce another annotation, lets say, `@Requires(classTypes={B.class})`, which should be added along with the `@Subscribe`. This kind of an auxiliary/associate annotation could then be used when constructing the `Subscriber`/`SubscriberRegistry` (possibly using a `Predicate<Class>`). In this case, the listeners could simply have

```
/**
 * Listens for B or C created event
 */
@Subscribe
@Requires(classTypes={B.class, C.class})
public void handleCreatedEvent(ACreatedEvent event) {
    //handle B and C created event
}
```

and the I would only need to have the three `Event` classes for the base class (`ACreatedEvent`, `AUpdatedEvent`, `ADeletedEvent`) and listeners who are specifically interested in the subclass events can have `@Requires` annotation.

But the problem is, Guava doesn't expose those core classes.

So, my questions are:

1. Why Guava wanted the logic of Subscribers private?
2. I am working on a commercial product. Can I copy the eventbus module into my code base and give my own implementation (a new implementation without changing the existing implemantation) for `Subscriber` and `SubscriberRegistry` and changing the `EventBus` to use my `SubscriberRegistry` class? (without changing the rest of the classes and their copyright statements) Will that violate the Apache License 2.0?

[PS: Sorry for this long question. `@Requires` is just an example. The idea of the question was the possible extensible behavior for `@Subscribe`]

Comment: In short, because Guava wanted to be able to change that implementation detail without breaking everyone who decided to extend it.

Comment: `Will that violate the Apache License 2.0?` No, while you notice the modifications properly. Read paragraph "4. Redistribution".

Comment: This doesn't make much sense as a StackOverflow question (there's not really an answer beyond what Louis said), but it does make sense as a feature request. File an [issue](https://github.com/google/guava/issues) describing your use case and why the current behavior isn't sufficient and you may just get your wish in a subsequent release.