# How to configure Guava EventBus Dispatcher?

Tags: guava

I want to configure Guava EventBus, but its constructor is package private.
I'm using `Guava Version:26.0-jre`

Answer (score 1):

The constructor you're referring to (and `Dispatch` class itself) are implementation details of Guava and you shouldn't use it. Most probably you want to pass custom `Executor` to [`AsyncEventBus`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/27.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/eventbus/AsyncEventBus.html), it'll be used to dispatch events.

Custom `Dispatchers` aren't allowed IMO because it's hard to implement queuing in reliable and thread-safe manner and library creators decided to disallow such possibility.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28104575/why-guava-eventbus-the-module-is-not-extensible?rq=1